# VS Code keeps opening new terminal in a home folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, integrated-terminal-window

I do want a new terminal window in VS Code to open in a project folder which should be a default behavior. However this is not the case and the new terminal keeps opening in a home folder for all workspaces. Any ideas of what can be causing this?

- OS: macOS 14.1 (Sonoma)
- VS Code: 1.87.2

I tried changing the `terminal.integrated.cwd` setting. By default it was empty. I tried setting it to `${workspaceFolder}` for the user, for the workspace, and for the folder in different combinations. A also tried to change it to the full folder path explicitly. I expected this to change where the terminal opens but none of the changes show any result.